# In $S_4$, what does the expression for the cyclic group $\langle (13),(1234)\rangle$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In $S_4$, what does the expression for the cyclic group $\langle (13),(1234)\rangle$ mean?

I apologize if this is too basic, but I haven't come across such an expression anywhere in my book. Also, not much success on the web regarding what does $\langle (13),(1234)\rangle$ actually mean? How is it evaluated?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is the subgroup generated by $(13)$ and $(1234)$. You can get the elements explicitly by multiplying $(13)$ by itself and $(1234)$ until you no longer get any new elements, and then you multiply every combination of those elements. In words, it is the smallest subgroup of $S_4$ containing those elements.

Comment: Also, here's more of an explanation. See page 4 http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/427-13/sgps.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle(13),(1234)\rangle$ is NOT a cyclic group! A cyclic group is a group generated by a single element, the one you wrote is a subgroup of $S_4$ generated by TWO elements, $(13)$ and $(1234)$.

In general given a group $G$, taken $g_1,\dots,g_n\in G$, the expression $\langle g_1,\dots,g_n\rangle$ denotes the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains the $g_i$'s which is the intersection of all the subgroups of $G$ containing all the $g_i$'s.

In your case, you can write down explicitly the elements of the subgroup $\langle(13),(1234)\rangle$: it's formed by all the product of integers power of the elements $(13)$ and $(1234)$. Hence a typical element of $\langle(13),(1234)\rangle$ is $(13)^{k_1}(1234)^{k_2}(13)^{k_3}\dots$ with $k_i\in\mathbb Z$. Being $(13)$ an element of order $2$ you can wlog think the element of your group as $(13)(1234)^{h_1}(13)(1234)^{h_2}\dots$ and $(1234)^{h_1}(13)(1234)^{h_2}(13)\dots$ with $h_i\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I got this group as : $\{ 1,(13),(1234),(1234)^2,(1234)^3,(13)(1234),(13)(1234)^2,(13)(1234)^3\}$ .. I just saw on another webpage that this is isomorphic to $D_4$ . In general, how should we find out $D_n$  is isomorphic to which subgroup of $S_4$ ?

Comment: $D_n$ has order $2n$ hence being $|S_4|=24$ and being its subgroups of order dividing $24$, the only possibilities for $D_n$ to be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$ is for (assumed $n>4$) $n=6$. But $|D_6|=12$ and the only subgroup of $S_4$ of such an order is $A_4$. Check if $D_6$ could be isomorphic to $A_4$ (look for example at the order of certain elements).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is not "cyclic", that would be the case if it is only *one* element of $S_4$. But this is a generalization - the group *generated by two elements* namely $(13)$ and $(1234)$. So write down all elements that can be made with powers and products of these elements, for example $(13)\cdot(1234)\cdot(1234)\cdot (13)\cdot (1234)$ is an element. Can you work out which subgroup of $S_4$ the group $\langle(13),(1234)\rangle$ represents?

Comment: ohk ..  so this group should comprise the following elements : $\{ 1,(13),(1234),(1234)^2,(1234)^3,(13)(1234),(13)(1234)^2,(13)(1234)^3\}$

Comment: Am I correct .. ?

Comment: And to be completely clear, "powers" includes negative powers too. Another way to describe $\langle a,b\rangle$ is "all finite products you can make only using $a,b,a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. For finite groups one can get away with just "powers," but when we get to infinite groups we'll be glad we mentioned this :)

Comment: @nicky and @ rschwieb Thank you for your answers :-)

Comment: Very good remarks of all, and yes @VHP you were correct in identifying the group - it is isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: The way isomorphism to $D_4$ was or should  be determined was through examining the orders of elements on both sides right?

Comment: Well, be careful, in general, if two groups have the same number of elements of a specific order, then they DO NOT have to be isomorphic. This has been discussed on this forum before - have to look up the reference. Most of the time the presentation of $D_4$ is $\langle a,b : a^4=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\rangle$. From this you can construct an isomorphism mapping $(1234)$ to $a$ and $(13)$ to $b$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693163/groups-with-same-number-of-elements-of-each-order for my remark above.