# If two finite groups have the same number of elements of the same order, does this necessarily imply they are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I am trying to prove a rather difficult question and I have arrived at a small proof that I can prove true after thoroughly (and exhaustively) analyzing the group structure.

My question is, if two finite groups have the same number of elements of the same order... are they necessarily isomorphic? If not, what are some properties of the group structure that can show that two groups are necessarily isomorphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, finite groups of the same order are not isomorphic. Indeed, this is far from true. So there are, for example, 49 487 365 422 pairwise non-isomorphic groups of order $1024$. This is a lot.
On the other hand, two cyclic groups of the same order are indeed isomorphic.

Edit: The question has been changed now, asking about the order of elements. This has been answered here already (see the duplicate).

Comment: The OP accepted your answer but actually this is not an answer to his question. Because he wants  "the same number of elements of the same order"

Comment: @miracle173 It was the answer to the *original* question. I have also answered the new question at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296833/if-i-know-the-order-of-every-element-in-a-group-do-i-know-the-group/1296867#1296867).

Comment: Thank you, I think it is the duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: Why the downvote? the original question was whether two finite groups of the same order need to be isomorphic.