# Classifying groups of order 8 without using conjugation

Tags: group-theory

I know that solutions to this exercise can be found quite easily but I have tried to solve it on my own and I'm stuck on the last case. I would be glad if someone could tell me if this is correct and how to continue:

The only case remaining is that $G$ has an element of order 4, say $g$. Then $\langle g\rangle$ is a normal subgroup.

1. Let's assume that there is an element $h$ of order 2 which is not $g^2$.  Then $\langle h\rangle\cap\langle g\rangle=\{e\}$ and $\langle h\rangle\langle g\rangle=G$, so $G=\langle g\rangle\rtimes\langle h\rangle\cong\mathbb Z_4\rtimes\mathbb Z_2\cong D_4$.
2. Let's assume there is no such element $h$. So the only element of order 2 in $G$ is $g^2$. But then $G$ has 6 elements of order 4. Can I conclude that $G\cong Q_8$ from that when knowing that $Q_8$ has 6 elements of order 4 and one each of order 1 and 2? I'm not sure if having elements with the same order yields an isomorphism.

> Edit: Maybe my question can be reduced to: Are there groups of the same order with all elements having identical order that are not isomorphic?

Comment: Yes there are, but **not** among the groups of order 8. See: [If I know the order of every element in a group, do I know the group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296833/if-i-know-the-order-of-every-element-in-a-group-do-i-know-the-group)

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting. So is there a way to continue my proof without taking the "usual" way of cosets?

Comment: Well, 8 is not all that much, so you might be able to do the trick simply by careful consideration of the Cayley tables.

Comment: But why would you want to avoid cosets?

Comment: Because I would like to see if one can obtain this result with a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to construct an isomorphism $Q_8 \to G$, you first need to decide which definition of $Q_8$ you want to use. If you say e.g.
$$ Q_8 := \langle i,j \mid i^4 = j^4 = 1, i^2=j^2, ij = ji^{-1} \rangle, $$
then you only need to find two generators $g,h \in G$ of order four satisfying $g^2 = h^2$ and $gh = hg^{-1}$. Another way of defining $Q_8$ (among many others) is
$$ Q_8 := (C_4 \rtimes C_4)/N, $$
where $N$ is a certain normal subgroup of order two. In this case you need to construct an epimorphism $C_4 \rtimes C_4 \to G$ with kernel $N$. Now a morphism $C_4 \rtimes C_4 \to G$ is essentially the same as a pair of elements $g,h \in G$ with $g^4=h^4=1$ and $g^h = g^{-1}$. It is epimorphic if and only if $g$ and $h$ generate $G$. So you see we are doing exactly the same as before.

Comment: My definition is $Q_8:=\langle i,j|i^2=j^2=-1, ij=-ji\rangle$. If I take any $h\in G-\langle g\rangle$ as my $j$ and $g$ as my $i$ then $g^2=h^2=-1$ is trivial. But how can I conclude $gh=-hg$?

Comment: @Buh: Since $\langle h \rangle$ is normal in $G$ and $h$ is of order four, we have $h^g \in \{ h, h^{-1} \}$. If $h^g = h$ then $G$ would be abelian, so it must be $h^g = h^{-1}$. Btw: Your definition is a bit strange. What is $-1$ or $-ji$?

Comment: Okay, thanks!
PS: With $-1$ I meant $-1=-\mathrm{1}_2\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$.