# Finite Abelian groups with the same number of elements for all orders are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite abelian groups.

Suppose that for every natural number $m$, the number of elements of order $m$ in $A$ is equal to the number of elements of order $m$ in $B$.

Prove that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic.

---

#### Idea

Given that these groups are finite, I think you have to use the primary decomposition theorem somehow.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Mathmo123 They do. Can you show me an element of finite order in $A$ that has a different order than an element of finite order in $B$? =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff ah of course, the obvious one. I stand corrected.

Comment: my mistake, it is given that theses groups are finite, i think you have to use the primary decomposition theorem somehow...

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/two-finite-abelian-groups-with-the-same-number-of-elements-of-any-order-are-isom

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would look at it. Suppose you are given the order $g$ of the group which has canonical factorization $p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_n} \dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$. By the fundamental theorem of finite group your group is direct product of $n$ abelian $p$-groups, which are in turn direct products of cyclic subgroups of different orders. We want to determine for each prime which $p$-group is being used.

To do this look at the elements whose order has only $p$ as a prime divisor. Those are the elements which are of the form $(1,1,1,g,1,1\dots 1)$ These elements form a subgroup which is isomorphic to the $p$-subgroup.

So we would like to discern which subgroup it is by knowing the elements of order power of $p$.

To prove we can do this we need to prove that if

$\mathbb Z_{p^{a_1}}\times\mathbb Z_{p^{a_2}}\dots \mathbb Z_{p^{a_r}}$ and $\mathbb Z_{p^{b_1}}\times\mathbb Z_{p^{b_2}}\dots \mathbb Z_{p^{b_s}}$ are groups of order $p^n$ with different exponents they have a different count of orders.

To see this note that the order of an element in a direct product $g=(g_1,g_2\dots g_n)$ is the least common multiple of all of the orders, in a $p$-group it is the highest order.

So go order the factors from least to greatest. and suppose they differ for the first time at factor $k$, where the first group has a larger exponent (call it $p^x$) Then that group has more elements of order $p^x$.

Comment: i still do not understand why in the last claim, if the first  group has a larger exponent(p^x) the group must have more elements of order p^x.

Comment: Well, that isn't true by itself, the point is that an element of the direct product in a p-group has order $p^x$ if and only if the element that has the highest order inside the parenthesis has order $p^x$. We take the two p-groups and write them out in decreasing order of the exponenents and look at the first part where they are different ok?

Comment: So call the product of the first factors that are equal $K$ and let the groups be $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Then $G=K\times Z_{p^x}\times Z_{p^{g_1}}\dots$ and $H=K\times Z_{p^y}\times Z_{p^{h_1}}\dots$. We only care about $p^x$ and $p^y$, suppose $x>y$, then $G$ has more elements of order $x$, why? they both have the elements of order $p^x$ that have that order because of the factor coming from $K$, but $G$ has more, those afforder by having an element from $Z_{p^x}$

Comment: i get it now, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be able to!

Comment: to prove, I made a massive typo

Comment: But there may be a problem even if we arrange them in decreasing order of exponents, even if $x>y$, $H$ may have a longer chain of direct summands. In this case, we can change the elements in the further summands, i.e. having lesser power of $p$ as order, and get more elements of $H$ having order $p^x$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in general. Take $A = \mathbb{Q}, B = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}.$ Even if you assume that the groups contains "some" elements of finite order, then also it is not true. Take $A = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, B = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $m > 1$ is an integer.

But if you choose $A$ and $B$ to be finite, then it is true. This follows from the [structure theorem of finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group). Note also that it is not true even for finitely generated abelian groups which are not finite. Take $A = \mathbb{Z}^r, B = \mathbb{Z}^s, r\neq s.$

$\bf{EDIT:}$ Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite abelian groups. Then $A \cong \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_2\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/d_r\mathbb{Z},$ for some $d_1, d_2, \cdots ,d_r \in \mathbb{Z}$ are prime powers (not necessarily distinct). Similarly $B \cong \mathbb{Z}/e_1\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/e_2\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/e_s\mathbb{Z},$ for some $e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_s \in \mathbb{Z}$ are prime powers (not necessarily distinct). The numbers $d_i$ and $e_j$ are uniquely determined by $A$ and $B$ respectively. So by the given condition, we must have $r = s, d_i = e_i, \forall i.$ This shows that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic.

Comment: "So by the given condition..." That's a big jump there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: what I wrote was wrong. we need prime powers. other wise it need not be true,e.g. $d_1 = 6, d_2=5, e_1=2, e_2 = 3, e_3 = 5.$ now I've fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.