# If two groups $G,G^{'} $ of order $n$ are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we have two groups $G,G^{'} $ of order $n$ and both have the same number of elements of a given order then are the two groups isomorphic?

I meant that if $o(G)=o(G^{'})=n$ and if $G$ has $p$  elements of order $m$ then $G^{'}$ has also $p$ elements of order $m$ and this holds for each $m\in \Bbb N$ ,
then are $G,G^{'} $ isomorphic?

Comment: You mean $G$ has $p$ elements of order $m$ if and only if $G'$ has $p$ elements of order $m$ for every $m$?

Comment: They are **finite** groups, aren't they?

Comment: Yes they are@ajotatxe

Comment: Seems like induction on order of the groups and quotients sholud do the work... (Only guessing).

Comment: Strongly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729611, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296833

Comment: In the Abelian case, yes, in the non-Abelian case, no. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693163/groups-with-same-number-of-elements-of-each-order and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/two-finite-abelian-groups-with-the-same-number-of-elements-of-any-order-are-isom